# Existence of model of ZF without AC, but with many choice function

Tags: axiom-of-choice, set-theory

Question 1: Does there exist models of the Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory without the axiom of choice, but such that every indexed family of non-void sets whose index set has a well-orderable cardinal admits a choice function ?
Question 2: The same as question 1, with "a well-orderable cardinal" replaced by "a linearly ordered cardinal".
Gérard Lang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question:

Yes. It is known that the axiom "Every well-orderable family of non-empty set has a choice function" implies $DC$ but not $DC_{\aleph_1}$.

You can find the proofs in Jech's "The Axiom of Choice" and in Felgner's "Models of ZF-Set Theory".

I am not sure about the second question, but I believe the answer should be "yes" as well.

In [Consequences of the Axiom of Choice](http://consequences.emich.edu/CONSEQ.HTM) you can find the following principles:

1. **Form 1** is the axiom of choice.
2. **Form 202** is the existence of a choice function for linearly ordered families of non-empty sets.
3. **Form 40** is the existence of a choice function for well-ordered families of non-empty sets.

Entering those three numbers in the table show that $1\implies 202\implies 40$ and neither implications is reversible. Although in the case of $202\implies 1$ this is in a weaker axioms system without regularity.

---

**Edit:** I had a bit more time now, so I went to chase after the cited source for Form 202:

> Truss, J. **The axiom of choice for linearly ordered families.** *Fund. Math.* **99* (1978), no. 2, 133–139. ([MR480029](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=480029))

Here is an excerpt from the review:

> The axiom of choice for linearly ordered families asserts that any linearly ordered family of nonempty sets has a choice function. The author shows that in ZF this statement implies the full axiom of choice, while in FM (ZF without the axiom of foundation) it does not.

So it seems that in ZF, requiring for linearly ordered families is enough to require the full axiom of choice.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, assuming $ZF+AD$ is consistent, is $ZF+AD$ consistent with "there exists a well-orderable uncountable subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Tomek, no. Under ZF+AD the perfect set property is true, and every set of reals is countable or of size continuum. It follows that if the continuum can be well-ordered the perfect set property fails, and so the only well-ordered sets of real numbers are countable in models of ZF+AD.

Comment: THANK you very much Asaf. The link with Consequences of the axiom of choice is most interesting. Concerning Jech's book, I only found exercises 4.14 and 5.22 relatives to the proof that AC for well-ordered sets does not prove AC; but this is the case where every non-void set of the indexed family is well-orderable, not the case where the index set is itself well-orderable.
Gérard Lang

Comment: Dear Gerhard, check Chapter 8 in Jech's book. 

Comment: Dear Asaf, thank you very much for going until Truss article.
Alas, Fund Math seems to be no more freely accessible. Anyway, this  gives a most interesting result, notably considering that (as results of Jech's formidable book) the Ordering Principle does not imply the Prime Ideal Theorem, and so also not the Axiom of Choice. Moreover,following your indications, I found theorem 8.12 about failing of the Dependent Choice and nevertheless obtaining AC(l) and W(l) for any cardinal l<k, where k is a regular cardinal.
Gérard Lang


Comment: Dear Gerard, check Theorem 8.9 in Jech's book. It should answer your question. Generally speaking, though, DC is a very strong form of limited choice, and in my view it is the "true form of limited choice". Fundamenta has freely accessible (I think) archives, but the relevant volume does not appear in those archives. I'll try to come up with a good argument and I'll update my answer if I find one.

Comment: Dear Asaf, let me thank you very much to answer my messages. I found theorem 8.9 in Jech's book and had not previously seen that it implied
the existence of a model of ZF where AC fails and every family of non-vois sets whose index set is well-orderable admits a choice function !
Gérard Lang 