# what axioms are between AC and Countable choice !

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Hi All. Need some information. We all know axiom of choice (AC) and countable choice. Which axioms are between these two. I mean weaker that Axiom of choice but stronger than countable choice ?

Comment: What do you need this information for?  Do you have a specific theorem that follows from ZFC  but not from ZF+Countable choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependent choice, for example. Or choice for well-ordered families, see [Existence of model of ZF without AC, but with many choice function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118060)

Answer (score 5):

There are many many many axioms.

For example you have the **Principle of Dependent Choice**, you also have the generalized axiom of choice for $\kappa$, "For every family of size $\kappa$ of non-empty sets there is a choice function." and whenever $\kappa>\aleph_0$ this is a strictly stronger axiom. In a similar fashion the principle of dependent choice is extended to what is known as $\mathsf{DC}_\kappa$.

There are many choice principles and they come in different flavours and shapes. Some good places to start would be:

1. Howard & Rubin's **Consequences of the Axiom of Choice**.
2. Herrlich's **The Axiom of Choice**.
3. G. Moore's **Zermelo's Axiom of Choice**.
4. Jech's **The Axiom of Choice**.